# Alternative for React with a low impact on DOM redraw

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, webgl, redux

I'm currently working an a project that uses WebGL in the 'background' of the website, with a UI-layer on top of it. I started off using react as my weapon of choice to handle the building and updating of the UI (together with redux). The problem I ran in to, is that calling setState in any component that is mounted at the time, causes my WebGL content (a spinning globe) to ever so slightly jitter.

It's been a while since I have used anything other than react, and I would like to keep redux for the data-fetching and the state management. So, my question is: What would be a good UI framework to use in this case, that has a low impact on DOM redraw? I already did a small proof of concept where I manipulate the DOM using Vanilla JS whilst listening to the redux store, and the jittering is gone. Ofcourse, jQuery would be an option but it seems... outdated? I use NPM and Webpack for building and package management. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If your UI is not overly complex and performance is what you need, you might simply want to try regular DOM manipulation. Because you use WebGL you absolutely can't do any heavy work in JavaScript or you will make your framerate suffer.

You could also start implementing `componentShouldUpdate` and other React performance tricks to try and get your update time under a single frame. It's hard but possible.